# Getting argument error when trying to reauthenticate with Link

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Using firebase auth to reauthenticate the already existing user, reauthenticate with credential is working fine, but credential with link is not,

```
import {
  EmailAuthProvider,
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  reauthenticateWithCredential,
} from "firebase/auth";
  if (user.email != email) {
    console.log(user.email, window.location.href);
    const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(
      user.email,
      window.location.href
    );
    reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential)
      .then(() => {
        return user.updateEmail(email);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

This is the error message -

```
{"code":"auth/argument-error","customData":{},"name":"FirebaseError"}
```

Or Let me put it this way -

**Am using react with firebase auth**

Firebase asking me to reauthenticate the user, but I only want to reauthenticate with an Email Link (old email) and then update it to new email ID